# How DeviceIoControl Returns a Null Terminated String from a Device Driver

Tags: winapi, usb, driver, device, wdk

Some drivers return a structure thru **DeviceIoControl** that contains a null-terminated string, say the symbolic name.  Where should be the location of that string?  For example, the USB host controller accepts **IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME** ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537326(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537326%28v=VS.85%29.aspx))which accepts a buffer to **USB_HCD_DRIVERKEY_NAME** structure as the output.  On a closer look, the **DriverKeyName** field of that structure [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539325(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539325%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)is just an array with 1 element of WCHAR type.  Where should be the actual driver key name be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fairly common pattern on Windows.  A struct will have something like `WCHAR SomeNameOrPath[1]` as the last field.  This allows for allocating a large buffer for the struct so that the bytes immediately after the struct can contain the rest of the string.

Comment: For IOCTL_USB_GET_ROOT_HUB_NAME example, does that mean I need to allocate a very large output buffer in my DeviceIoControl call rather than just a simple buffer of size = sizeof(USB_HCD_DRIVERKEY_NAME)?  If yes, how large should it be?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be large enough to hold both the USB_HCD_DRIVERKEY_NAME struct and the accompanying string.  You could try allocating a large buffer and hope it is big enough, but with this pattern you typically call the function twice - once to get the required size and then again after you have allocated the buffer.  MSDN has a sample on the IOCTL_GET_HCD_DRIVERKEY_NAME page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537236.aspx).

Comment: In the example shown by your link, the 2nd step checks if (nBytes <= sizeof(driverKeyName)). But nBytes should have been assigned driverKeyName.ActualLength.  Why enforce ActualLength to be greater than the structure size?  The 2 shouldn't be related!

Comment: I guess it's just a sanity check.  The remarks say that ActualLength is the size of the structure plus the size of the name.

Comment: And for the curious, more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx